# A question on uniformly corepresented functor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ct.category-theory, representable-functors

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a functor from the category of $k$-schemes to sets, uniformly corepresented by $M$. Suppose $U$ is an open subscheme of $M$. I could not find a good reference for uniformly corepresented. Is the fiber product $\mathcal{F} \times_{h_M} h_U$ corepresented by $U$?

Any good reference on uniform corepresented functor will be most helpful.

PS. Here $k$ is an algebraically closed field

Comment: If that is not part of the definition of "uniformly corepresented", then what definition are you using?  Some standard references for coarse moduli spaces and the various functorial properties they satisfy are Keel-Mori, Lieblich, and Conrad.

Comment: @JasonStarr I do not know if this is part of definition. I could not find a proper statement for this. There were some specific examples using coarse moduli spaces which said something similar, like uniformly corepresented is universally corepresented under flat base change. As I did not find any precise statement, I thought it might be better to get a reference with a precise reference. I guess from your comment that the standard definition of uniform corepresentation covers the property mentioned in my question!

Comment: Yes, uniformly corepresented means corepresented, even after flat base change.  Since open immersions are flat, if $\mathcal{F}\to h_M$ uniformly corepresents $\mathcal{F}$, then also $\mathcal{F}\times_{h_M} h_U \to h_U$ corepresents $\mathcal{F}\times_{h_M} h_U$.  The article by Keel-Mori includes a long list of properties such as this which some coarse moduli spaces satisfy.